# Importing Beat Link Java Library From Maven Central To Eclipse?

Tags: java, maven

This is the first time I have encountered Maven so I don't really know what I'm doing here.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to import the java library [Beat Link](https://github.com/Deep-Symmetry/beat-link) into my java code using Maven.

Could anyone please provide a simple step by step on how to do this in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On maven central you got the maven dependency text -

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.deepsymmetry</groupId>
<artifactId>beat-link</artifactId>
<version>0.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Once you create a maven project you should have a pom.xml file.
You need to add this text to the dependencies section of your pom.xml file.

If that doesnt make sense to you, do yourself a favor and read/watch a quick tutorial about using maven on a java project. It's pretty simple once you see how it works.